# Poping several view controllers but showing all of them

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have `UINavigationController` and several `UIViewControllers` pushed into it. What I'd like to implement is to pop let's say 2 view controllers back. However I'd like the previous controller in the stack be shown with animation before getting to the desired one (going thru it). This is the main reason why `popToViewController:` does not work for me.

Another thing I tried to call `popViewControllerAnimated:` with setting a flag to all previous `UIViewControllers` so that if flag is set, the view controller will invoke `popViewControllerAnimated:` in its `viewDidAppear:`. This gives me almost what I want, however I don't like the animation is not smooth. Animation slows down for each controller, while I want all of them passed at the same speed.

One more approach I'm thinking is to avoid these controllers and put everything into one scroll view, which would give me total control of how to make view transactions.

Still I wonder if there's something I can do with navigation controller?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt You will achieve smooth animation (maybe if you implement different function, rather than `viewDidAppear:` - then you can probably achieve it - for example - you have 3 `viewControllers` in stack - you pop third, and in the same time initiate pop for second, with a delay which is as long as pop animation (0.25? dunno, test it).  (you access second one from third via `[self.navigationController viewControllers]`) Maybe that works).

I dont really like the idea about all `viewControllers` (views) in a scrollview. - It could be too much memory consuming. Could.

Other option would be - store a screenshot from each viewController. If only smooth poping animation is required, then you can take a screenshot from each `viewController` (on background thread while `viewController` is opened.) and add it to global scrollview imageSet. Then when popping - shortly show that scrollview, and animate through images, while under scrollview, `viewControllers` have already been popped to necessary `viewController`.

(If some `viewController` content is changed dynamically - it may not be important, as user won't notice that from already taken screenshot which slides fast)

Hope you got some new ideas :)

Comment: Ok, I liked the idea of taking screenshots, as long as the content is static on previous view controllers in my app. I've implement it and will post solution here later in case somebody wants it. And another thing I'll try is to change animation curve for popping (if it's ever possible).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's details on how I implemented it

1. Define protocol `Screenshotable`, which will define if the look of `UIViewController` should be saved when next view controller is pushed into `UINavigationViewController`

   @protocol Screenshotable 
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *screenshot;
   @end
2. Make the view controllers implement the protocol and `@synthesize screenshot` whereever you implement the `Screenshotable` protocol.
3. Now define the delegate for your `UINavigationViewController` and implement the following callback as shown below:

   - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
     {
     // Getting the current view (this is the just pushed view) but we'd like to screenshot previous view controller as it hides
     int index = [[navigationController viewControllers] count] - 1;

     // Checking if this is the very first view controller and nothing to screenshot yet
     if (index <= 0) return;

     // Getting the previous one
     UIViewController *controller = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:--index];

     // Making screen shot if it's screenshotable
     if ([controller conformsToProtocol:@protocol(Screenshotable)])
     {
         id screenshotable = (id)controller;

     ```
     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
     {
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
     }
     else
     {
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
     }

     [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     screenshotable.screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     ```

     }
     }
4. Now all `UIViewControllers` in the navigation stack which implements `Screenshotable` protocol will store their view image just before new controller was pushed. Whenever you want go back thru all of them get the UIImages from controllers, add them into current controller and animate. When animation is over just invoke [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:NO];

That's it.